# Malformed URL Exception on Retrofit2 when path has another protocol name

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I am making the following call

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")    
@POST("{uri}")
Call<SolarWindsQueryResult<Object>> updateTestFlagForNode(@Path(value="uri",encoded = true/false) String Uri,@Body RunTestCases runTestCases);
```

So the URL I am trying to post to is

> https://hostname:port/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/swis://solarwinds-01./Orion/Orion.Nodes/NodeID=1/CustomProperties

The call to this method is as follows

```
solarWindsService.updateTestFlagForNode("swis://solarwinds-01./Orion/Orion.Nodes/NodeID=1/CustomProperties",new RunTestCases("true")).execute()
```

This call fails for both encoded true and false. I get the following exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL. Base: https://10.50.1.71:17778/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/, Relative: swis://solarwinds-01./Orion/Orion.Nodes/NodeID=1/CustomProperties/CustomProperties

Inside the retrofit code I see that the builder.parse(HttpUrl base,String input) returns UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME because its looking for HTTP or HTTPS in the input string and the HttpUrl returns null. It seems like Retrofit does not support this kind of a url or maybe I am doing something wrong. Need help. FYI, it works on chrome

I am able to bypass that code by using the @Url annotation but it would be nice if I could use the @Path to still perform the above request.

Answer (score 2):

okhttp only supports http/https.  It is parsing your path as a full url before trying to figure out how to merge it with the base and the non-http scheme is causing you trouble.  You can make it look more like a `path` by adding a relative reference to the current path at the front --

`@POST("./{uri}")`

or you can do it on the call --

`solarWindsService.updateTestFlagForNode("./swis://solarwinds-01./Orion/Orion.Nodes/NodeID=1/CustomProperties",new RunTestCases("true")).execute()`

Comment: Unfortunately this trick doesn't work any more starting **Retrofit 2.5.0** due to this fix - [Forbid path traversal ('.' and '..') as @path parameters](https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/b9a7f6ad72073ddd40254c0058710e87a073047d)